# How to have an `@Autowired` object in a `SpringBootContextLoader`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsorsCrucibleTestsConfiguration {
  public AtomicReference<Functions.FailableFunction<MergedContextConfiguration, ApplicationContext, Exception>> crucibleApplicationContextFunction() {
    return new AtomicReference<>(null);
  }
```

```
public class SettableApplicationContextLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {
  public class SettableApplicationContextLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {
  @Autowired
  private AtomicReference<FailableFunction<MergedContextConfiguration, ApplicationContext, Exception>> applicationContextFunction;

  // use `applicationContextFunction`
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SettableApplicationContextLoader.class)
class CucumberStepsBase {
}
```

But when it's time to use `applicationContextFunction`, it's `null`. Is there a way to have it injected into the context loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context loader creation happens before the dependency injection occurs in your application. If you use breakpoints, you will see that you pass into your `SettableApplicationContextLoader` before passing through your `ConsorsCrucibleTestsConfiguration` bean method.

What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Maybe this could be a better start.

Comment: We have an app that runs functional tests. If the functional test is being run within the app, it should use its `ApplicationContext`. Otherwise, it should use whatever `SpringBootTest` usually creates. We already have something working using a `static` member. I was hoping the `static` could somehow be replaced by injection. There's no way to set a `Configuration` specific to the context loader I guess?

Comment: Well... you try to run your tests, and your application at the same time, and you want to reuse the application context. Why that ? Because you can’t start both at the same time ? Do you have collision with the port ? Check the annotation `@SpringBootTest`, you can use a different port if you are running a web application

Comment: We want the app to run the tests so that test runs can be distributed across instances. We want to be able to run the tests standalone to ease development (ie the app doesn't have to be started/restarted each time the test is updated and running the test can be done directly in the IDE rather than through the Swagger UI of the app). Without setting the `loader` of the test so that the app can set the `ApplicationContext` to be used, the test isn't able to find an `ApplicationContext` when run from the app.

Comment: It seems to me you have two needs and therefor, two separated apps: the main one, running on production, which is testable when you develop; a second one to make distributed tests, which a completely different application. I'd go for making a complete other application to make such complicated tests.

Comment: We have two apps, the service-under-test and the test runner. The test runner will run tests against the service-under-test.

We also have two contexts in which the tests can be run:
1. from within the test runner (in which case the tests can just use its `ApplicationContext`)
2. directly from the IDE (in which the test can't use the test runner's `ApplicationContext`)